# Using Spatial Join in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, fields-attributes

i have 2 polygons one is building footprints and another is boundary polygons. i want to calculate the count of building footprint which falling inside the boundary polygon. in order to avoid duplication of the building footprint count, i used 'HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN' option in spatial join. but the problem is that i couldn't count the footprints which fall inside the boundary polygon.

how can i count the building footprints which falling inside the boundary polygon[image: image showing both building footprint as small black polygons and red line as boundary.i want to calculate the count of building footprints which falling inside the boundary(red line). the footprint should not repeat while counting.]?

Comment: You need to add more information about your data, for example add a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Under [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) You can use the `Sum` option under [Field Mapping](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/using-the-field-mapping-control.htm) to sum total of input field values. Based on the above help:

> Field Mapping controls what attribute fields will be in the output feature class.
>   The initial list contains all the fields from both the target features
>   and the join features. Fields can be added, deleted, renamed, or have
>   their properties changed. The selected fields from the target features
>   are transferred as is, but selected fields from the join features can
>   be aggregated by a merge rule

Here is another help on [Mapping input fields to output fields](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/python/mapping-fields.htm), which can give more details.